# How to de- and activate a checkbox in a table and also in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does someone know how to change the value of an array if the user clicks a checkbox?

Basically I have 3 text fields (name,date,place) and a checkbox (favorite). If the user inserts something and clicks the button, you will see the data in the table bellow and the data will also saved in an array.

My question is: How can I change the value "true"(is checked) into "false"  , so the user has the option of de- and activating an "person" as a favourite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add checked `attribute` to your `checkbox` based on your `favorite` `boolean` value. Read the comments in `javascript` section

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var allArtists = [];


  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var $rowTemplate = $('<tr><td data-id="id"></td><td data-id="name"></td><td data-id="geburtsort"></td><td data-id="geburtsdatum"></td><td data-id="favorite"></td></tr>');

    var artistName = $("#name").val();
    var ort = $("#ort").val();
    var datum = $("#datum").val();
    var favourite = $("[name=Favorit]").is(':checked');

    allArtists.push([artistName, ort, datum]);

    var rowId = allArtists.length;

    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=id]').text(rowId);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=name]').text(artistName);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsort]').text(ort);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsdatum]').text(datum);
    var checked = favourite ? "checked" : "";
    //if favourite==true then add checked value to checked variable otherwise keep it empty

    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=favorite]').html('<div class="chkText">'+favourite+'</div>').append($('<input type="checkbox" id="fave" ' + checked + '>'));
    //just assign it as property to your checkbox.

    $("#table tbody").append($rowTemplate);
  });
};

$("#table").on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
  $(this).prev('div').text($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```css
.chkText{
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Künstler hinzufügen</h1>
<form id="send">
  <label>Name des Künstlers</label>
  <br>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name des Künstlers" />
  <br>

  <label>Ort</label>
  <br>
  <input id="ort" type="text" placeholder="Woher stammt der Künstler" />
  <br>

  <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
  <br>
  <input id="datum" type="text" placeholder="Wann ist der Künstler geboren?" />
  <br>
</form>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" value="Favorit">Favorit
  <p>

    <input type="button" id="submit" name="senden" value="Senden">
    <table id="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Geburtsort</th>
          <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
          <th>Favorit</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>


    </table>
```

Please make a note that you are creating duplicate `id` here in your dynamic `html` generation, while adding `rows` to `table` where as it is **not allowed to have `duplicate id` in `html`**

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is really good but how can I change it into true if I click in the table? The table should be updated in real time. Do you know that ? I'm looking for hours now

Comment: @Addy2311, I've updated my answer and have added a `change` event to `checkbox` at the end of `js` plus a small `css` to align text of `checkbox` properly. Also please see the `change event` written and read about `event delegation`, as events to dynamically created elements should be attached with `event delegation`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801344/de-and-activating-a-checkbox-in-a-table-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment68823969_40801344 can you have a look at that